# I can't solve this C++ exercise

Tags: c++

I either get a infinity loop, 0, or 9. The question reads as follows:

> Create a for loop that compares the two strings starting from index 0. For each match, add one point to user score Upon a mismatch, exit the loop using a break statement.

```
int main() {
string simonPattern;
string userPattern;
int userScore = 0;
int i = 0;

userScore = 0;
simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

/* Your solution goes here  */

cout << "userScore: " << userScore << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Some of my tries:

```
for ( i = 0; simonPattern <= userPattern; ++i ) {
  while( simonPattern.at(0) == userPattern.at(0) ) {
      ++userScore;
     if( simonPattern.at(0) != userPattern.at(0) ){
        break;
     }
  }
   while ( simonPattern.at(1) == userPattern.at(1) ) {
      ++userScore;
     if( simonPattern.at(1) != userPattern.at(1) ){
        break;
     }
```

So until 9.
Another one:

```
for (int i=0;i < simonPattern.length(); ++i) {
userScore = i ; }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You said you get an infinity loop, 0, or 9, but what do those attempts look like?

Comment: updated the description with two of my attempts,

Comment: Your first attempt is comparing two strings in your loop, and since neither string changes you'll either have 0 or infinite iterations. The second attempt's loop condition is better, although the body is incorrect.

Comment: ive tried the second one with body of the first, but that wasn't much better, also tried to make it work without the for loop, still no luck

Comment: You should google levensthein distance, maybe this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't understand what you tried to do in your first approach.

Will modify your second approach here a bit, by adding comparision in the loop body for when to increment score and when to exit from loop, and also changing the loop termination condition a bit.

**Approach**
We are using the variable userScore to keep track of score of user. Also storing length of the two strings in variables simonPatternLength and userPatternLength to keep track of when one ends.

For the indices of the strings starting from 0, till one of them ends do the following -
   1. If current index is equal in both increase userScore by 1
   2. else upon mismatch break out of loop

**Code**

```cpp
int main() {
string simonPattern;
string userPattern;
int userScore = 0;
int i = 0;

userScore = 0;
simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

/* Your solution goes here  */
int simonPatternLength = simonPattern.size();
int userPatternLength = userPattern.size();

for(i = 0; i < simonPatternLength && i < userPatternLength; ++i){
    if(simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i]){
        userScore++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}

cout << "userScore: " << userScore << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping solve this, i have been at this problem a while now.

Comment: also the use of [ i ] brackets and the variable in that way is new to me, i will have to do some googling

Comment: Here, operator [] helps you to access indices in the array starting from 0 to length of the string - 1. userScore++ increases userScore's value by 1. Simmilarly userScore-- would have decreased its value by 1.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that, as it happens the next chapter im learning talks about arrays and vectors, so it fits in nicely. however it also means that same problem i had to solve without the use of an array as it hasn't yet been introduced to me.

Comment: ok so i am going through some course material and woundering why your syntax    is  `if(simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i])`   and not  `if (simonPattern.at(i) == userPattern.at(i) ) `

Comment: can you not use line  breaks in comments

Comment: Dean, the difference between operator[] and the at() function from strings is that even even though both allow you to access the index in their argument, the at function throws an exception if you give it an invalid argument, while with the []operator  your program will face runtime error.